# Checking if a NumPy array contains another array

Tags: python, numpy

Using NumPy with Python 2.7, I want to create an n-by-2 array `y`. Then, I want to check whether this array contains a particular 1-by-2 array `z` in any of its rows.

Here's what I have tried so far, and in this case, n = 1:

```
x = np.array([1, 2]) # Create a 1-by-2 array
y = [x] # Create an n-by-2 array (n = 1), and assign the first row to x
z = np.array([1, 2]) # Create another 1-by-2 array
if z in y: # Check if y contains the row z
    print 'yes it is'
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You can do `(y == z).all(1).any()`.

To go into a bit more detail, numpy will element-by-element comparisons across higher dimensions automatically using something called "broadcasting".  So if `y` is your n-by-2 array, and `z` is your 1-by-2 array, `y == z` will compare each row of `y` with `z` element-by-element.  Then you can just use `all(axis=1)` to get the rows where all elements match, and `any()` to find out if any match.

So here it is in practice:

```
>>> y1 = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 2]])
>>> y2 = np.array([[100, 200], [100,300], [100, 200], [200, 200]])
>>> z = np.array([1, 2])
>>>
>>> (y1 == z).all(1).any()
True
>>> (y2 == z).all(1).any()
False
```

This is considerably faster than doing a loop or generator-based approach since it vectorizes the operation.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `any((z == x).all() for x in y)`. I don't know if it is the fastest, though.

Comment: This will be pretty slow since it doesn't vectorize the code.  I tried with `n=10000` and this approach is more than 140 times slower than a vectorized approach.

Comment: Yes, I actually have upvoted your answer and specified that I had doubts about the speed in mine. Nevertheless, the OP had no explicit requirements about speed, so I don't think I should delete my answer; but I think yours should be the one marked as accepted.