# Can I find out if one numpy vector appears as a slice of another?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to find out if my numpy vector, `needle`, appears inside another vector, `haystack`, as a slice, or contiguous sub-vector.

I want a function `find(needle, haystack)` that returns true if and only if there are possible integer indexes *p* and *q* such that `needle` equals `haystack[p:q]`, where "equals" means elements are equal at all positions.

Example:

```
find([2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]) == True
find([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5]) == False  # not contiguous inside haystack
find([2,3,4], [0,1,2,3]) == False  # incomplete
```

Here I am using lists to simplify the illustration, but really they would be numpy vectors (1-dimensional arrays).

For strings in Python, the equivalent operation is trivial: it's `in`: `"bcd" in "abcde" == True`.

---

An appendix on dimensionality.

Dear reader, you might be tempted by similar looking questions, such as [testing whether a Numpy array contains a given row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [Checking if a NumPy array contains another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217660/checking-if-a-numpy-array-contains-another-array?noredirect=1&lq=1). But we can dismiss this similarity as not being helpful by a consideration of dimensions.

A vector is a one-dimensional array. In `numpy` terms a vector of length *N* will have `.shape == (N,)`; its shape has length 1.

The other referenced questions are, generally seeking to find an exact match for a row in a matrix that is 2-dimensional.

I am seeking to slide my 1-dimensional *needle* along the same axis of my 1-dimensional *haystack* like a window, until the entire *needle* matches the portion of the *haystack* that is visible through the window.

Comment: But those are lists not numpy vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a NumPy array contains another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217660/checking-if-a-numpy-array-contains-another-array)

Comment: If you are testing multiple "needles" against a single "haystack", [Burrows Wheeler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform) can be helpful. Looking at DNA alignment implementations might also be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with creating copies of the two arrays, you could fall back on Python `in` operator for byte objects:

```
def find(a, b):
  return a.tobytes() in b.tobytes()

print(
    find(np.array([2,3,4]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])),
    find(np.array([2,4]),   np.array([1,2,3,4,5])),
    find(np.array([2,3,4]), np.array([0,1,2,3])),
    find(np.array([2,3,4]), np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4])),
)

# True False False True
```

Comment: This is extremely witty.

Answer (score 0):

Try with list comprehension:

```py
def find(a,x):
    return any([x[i:i+len(a)]==a for i in range(1+len(x)-len(a))])
```

Outputs:

```py
print(find([2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]),
find([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5]),
find([2,3,4], [0,1,2,3]), find([2,3,4], [0,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4]))
>> True False False True
```

Comment: yes, this is the approach i went with. I was rather hoping that there would be an existing function that I had not found.